# I want to add slider in my wordpress page . I am not able to add it. Here is my code

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

```
add_shortcode('slider', 'team_slider_query');
function team_slider_query($atts, $content){

$args=array(
            'posts_per_page'    => 200,
        'post_type'         => 'teams',);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
          <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<?php 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
        $the_query->the_post();?>

        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

        <?php 
        $imghtml = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'full');
            $url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'slider-url', true);
        // get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

$output .= '<div class="item">
            <img src="https://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Hydrangeas-300x225.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="https://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/i3solutions-team-solutions-business-solutions-data-management-collaboration-application-development-300x129.jpg"/>
        </div>';

    }
$output .= '</div>';


    /* Restore original Post Data */
      wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    // no posts found
}
return $output;
}
```

Can someone explain me where i am wrong?
I want to add slider in my page. I have used shortcode operator. The above code is from my custompost file. I inspected all the css and js are being properly loaded. But still can't get the output. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that you have to create $output, before you can add to it? meaning that you can add $output=""; early in the code

Comment: also, how are you using your shortcode?

Comment: Adding shortcode in pages in wordpress admin panel

Comment: Also i am getting the images at front end but not getting in the slider form

Comment: What is 'custompost file'? The code needs to be in your functions.php file...